# iOS simulator version doesn't appear - Xcode 12.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, ios10

I want to test my app in iOS 10, I'm just have tried the flow of add a new iOS simulator like I've made in the past, but the iOS version that I downloaded dons't appear in the list.

I'm using the **Xcode 12.2**

[image: I've downloaded the iOS 10.3 version]

When I try to add a new simulator the iOS 10 doesn't appear in list:

[image: When I try to add a new simulator the iOS 10 download appear in list]

The iOS target is set to 10
[image]

Deployment target:
[image]

**Edit 1** - I have run this code "xcrun simctl list" in terminal, and that message appear (unavailable, The iOS 10.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.). It's look like sadly the macOS Big Sur 11.0 doesn't support the iOS 10.3.

Comment: I've edit the post and uploaded some images to be more clearly @meaning-matters

Comment: You have found the answer. Give it as an answer, not as part of the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'll give it for you, but feel free to give the same answer yourself.

Comment: How to test backward compatibility ?

Comment: This is what Apple did in the past. Poor backward compability. Many devices which function well but iOS out of date will be forced to obsolete.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a lot of research I've tried to add a simulator via terminal using "xcrun simctl list" to list the simulators available, one of the infos returned is:

```
iOS 10.3 (10.3.1 - 14E8301) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-3 
(unavailable The iOS 10.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)
```

It's look like sadly the macOS Big Sur 11.0 doesn't support the iOS 10.3.

I think it could be a bug and the Xcode shouldn't allow the download if this iOS version it's not supported, I found in the apple forum that in other macOS versions some thing like this error occurred, see more in the link below.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74848

Thanks @matt for the support, I really didn't know that I could answer my own question.

Comment: Good find! Same applies to iOS 11.0 now: `iOS 11.0 (11.0.1 - 15A8401) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-0 (unavailable, The iOS 11.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)`

Answer (score 1):

I’ve got some more information on this: When I right-click the devices in Window -> Devices, "Show in Run Destinations Menu" is checked on all the Simulators just like it is on my real devices, yet only the real devices show up.

Also, I just tried creating a new iOS project from scratch, but there was no option to run anything at all. I don’t even know how to set this up, though, because I use Unity for creating Xcode projects. But I can confirm that this issue shows up on all the Projects that I am working on. So it doesn’t seem to be project-specific.

Besides, when I updated to 6.2, the simulators still worked in 6.1. Only 6.2 was having this issue. Well, and then 6.3 and now 6.4.

In one of my previous posts I answered the problem has been resolved to some extent.

But ultimately I was informed everything on Xcode's side worked as expected.

The bug was Unity-related. There has never been an option to run a Unity build on both simulators and actual devices.

There was a bug showing the simulators even though they were not available.

Now everything works when building for simulators in Unity.