# Unable to download iOS 11 Simulators for XCode 13.2.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm unable to download iOS 11 Simulators for XCode 13.2.1
what should I do?

Comment: Did you find the solution? How did you test your app on iOS11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check supported simulators for specific Xcode version on [Apple Xcode support page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/).

Additionally, as [answered on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029447/ios-simulator-version-doesnt-appear-xcode-12-2#comment116429160_65042303), simulator availability depends on the installed MacOS version. While Xcode 13.2.1 seems to support iOS 11 simulators on Big Sur, on Monterey the lowest available version is 12.4.

Comment: So If I want to test my app on older simulators then it's impossible to do that?