# How to install iOS 11.x Simulator on Xcode 13.4?

Tags: ios

I'm developing and iOS app with iOS 11 support,
but with Xcode 13.4 update I'm missing the possibility to add / install iOS 11 simulator.
Is there any chance to have iOS 11.x simulator in Xcode 13.4?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sZla.png)

if there is any chance,
how to develop iOS app with iOS 11 ?

Comment: not possible from Xcode 13.4

Comment: how to develop iOS app with iOS 11 ?

Comment: Not possible, check this double thread with explanations https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567693/6808357

Comment: wow Thx! I can check. >>  https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from Xcode:

> **Window > Devices and Simulators > Simulators**

Click the `+` button and you will be able to install the desired version